# jQuery Ajax Success callback firing without making a request

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have an AJAX request which looks like this:

```
$.get('api/indicator/status_graph/'+self.indicator.get('id'), function(data) {
    self.actuals_graph(data);
    self.graphLoaded(true);
    self.graphError(false);
}).error(function(data) {
    self.graphError(true);
});
```

It's a fairy simple request honestly, and one that's repeat on another place on the page. The problem I'm getting is that the success callback is being called immediately upon the get function being called; Chrome's Network panel shows no request is made to the server at all. An almost identical piece of code called elsewhere works perfectly normally, and since there is no difference in the way or the timing of when they're called I honestly can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: That is very odd. And probably impossible. Did you add any breakpoints in your code?

Comment: `.error` is deprecated - use `.fail` instead.

Comment: @Neal Yeah, I did--that's how I figured out that it was immediately going in to the callback function instead of making a request. When I check the variables I find that all that's being passed to the data variable is an empty string (""), no actual content.

Comment: @moberemk well you are not passing any data...

Comment: @Neal that data should be coming from the _response_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem recently: the success callback was being triggered, the response data was an empty string, no request would show up in Developer Tools and no request would hit the webserver. Like you, I assumed it wasn't a cache issue because no evidence of a request (even a cached one) showed up anywhere.

However, I tried setting the `cache` parameter of the `ajax()` call to `false` and also set all kinds of no-cache headers on the original server reply (in Django, using the [@never_cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers) decorator), and the problem seems to be fixed. Two days in and the issue never resurfaced.

Comment: I AM SO GLAD THAT I AM NOT ALONE. But seriously that's probably the best advice I've gotten on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The request/response is most likely cached. Look at your debugger to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run something akin to Fiddler to see if your request is indeed being sent? Also, you said the success callback is fired immediately after the GET is invoked - is the data returned to your success callback appropriate?

One possibility is that chrome is pre-caching your request. You did mention that there is another piece of code making an almost identical call - is it actually identical? or close?

Comment: First thing I checked was the caching, but when I say nothing appears in the Network panel I do mean nothing--no request is made at all, with no indication of it being handled by a cache instead. And the other code is almost identical in that it follows the same basic logic, but has different variables being set and a different URL being called.

Comment: @moberemk There is a glitch in chrome debugger if you are filtering just xhr requests where some don't show. Clicking on any other filter, than back on xhr will make them appear.

Comment: @BradM That's good to know, but this is without any filter on; I have every request listed, including resource requests such as for CSS files and it still doesn't show.